# Jetty Service behind Traefik

Tags: traefik

I have a software package from a vendor that uses Jetty to provide web services.  When I put Traefik infront of it and access the frontend I get redirected to the backend URL.  For example the frontend URL is https://program.example.com/ and the backend (software) URL is http://192.168.1.1:8088/ when I browse to https://program.example.com/ i automatically get redirected to http://192.168.1.1:8088/.  Thoughts?

```
[backends.sample]
    [backends.sample.servers.sample]
        url = "http://192.168.1.1:8088/" 

[frontends.sample]
       backend = "sample"
[frontends.sample.routes.sample]
       rule = "Host:program.sample.com"
       passHostHeader = true
       useXForwardedFor = true
[frontends.sample.redirect]
       entryPoint = "https"
       permanent = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had 'passHostHeader' in the wrong place.

```
[frontends.sample]
   backend = "sample"
   passHostHeader = true
[frontends.sample.routes.sample]
   rule = "Host:program.sample.com"
   useXForwardedFor = true
[frontends.sample.redirect]
   entryPoint = "https"
   permanent = true
```